# Find exact string in string - PHP

Tags: php

How do I find exact `2,` in a string using strpos? Is it possible using strpos? The example below returns "Found" even though the match is NOT exact to what I need. I understand `2,` is matching with `22,`. It should return "Not Found". I am matching ID's in this example.

```
$string = "21,22,23,26,";
$find = "2,";

$pos = strpos($string, $find);
if ($pos !== false) {
   echo "Found";
} else {
   echo "Not Found";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the string is enormous, make an array and search it:

```
$string = "21,22,23,26,";
$arr = explode(",", $string);

// array_search() returns its position in the array
echo array_search("2", $arr);
// null output, 2 wasn't found
```

Actually, [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is probably faster:

```
// in_array() returns a boolean indicating whether it is found or not
var_dump(in_array("2", $arr));
// bool(false), 2 wasn't found 
var_dump(in_array("22", $arr));
// bool(true), 22 was found
```

This will work as long as your string is a comma-delimited list of values. If the string is really long, making an array may be wasteful of memory. Use a string manipulation solution instead.

#### Addendum

You didn't specify, but if by some chance these strings came from a database table, I would just add that the appropriate course of action would be to properly normalize it into another table with one row per id rather than store them as a delimited string.

Comment: I don't see this comma seperated string being longer than 20-30 at most. So I didn't make it it's own DB table

Answer (score 1):

Try with `explode` and `in_array`

Example:

```
$string = "21,22,23,26,";
$string_numbers = explode(",", $string);
$find = 2;
if (in_array($find, $string_numbers)) {
   echo "Found";
} else {
   echo "Not Found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match if you want to avoid arrays.

```
    $string = "21,22,23,26,";
    $find = '2';
    $pattern = "/(^$find,|,$find,|,$find$)/";
    if (0 === preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
        echo "Not Found";
    } else {
        echo "Found";
    }
```

This will find your id at beginning, middle or at the end of the string. Of course, I am assuming $string does not contain characters other than numbers and commas (like spaces).